# query start, due, complete dates for first and last time phases from phase tracking table

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate, max

[linked excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JbD9ISdWiG4xglaqQ-ryedArimEBRIdD)

I have a phase tracking table which consists of the fields record id, phase name, record order number etc:

```
RECORD_ID,phase,RECORD_ORDER,SUBMITTED_DATE,DUE_DATE,COMPLETED_DATE
1657,Initiate,0,03-Oct-17,06-Oct-17,04-Oct-17  
1657,Investigation,1,04-Oct-17,17-Oct-17,07-Oct-17  
1657,Initiate,2,08-Oct-17,10-Oct-17,10-Oct-17   
1657,Investigation,3,11-Oct-17,18-Oct-17,17-Oct-17  
1657,Approve,4,18-Oct-17,30-Oct-17,28-Oct-17  
1657,Completed,5,29-Oct-17,,29-Oct-17  
2378,Initiate,0,03-Oct-17,06-Oct-17,05-Oct-17  
2378,Completed,1,05-Oct-17,NULL,05-Oct-17  
3133,Initiate,0,03-Jun-17,06-Jun-17,04-Jun-17  
3133,Investigation,1,04-Jun-17,17-Jun-17,07-Jun-17  
3133,Initiate,2,08-Jun-17,10-Jun-17,10-Jun-17  
3133,Investigation,3,11-Jun-17,18-Jun-17,17-Jun-17
```

This table is very big and certain records have been re-routed multiple times, others haven't.

I have a requirement to create a report showing for each unique `record_id` for each phase the first time the record entered this phase (so the lowest `RECORD_ORDER` number) and the last time the record entered that phase (so highest `RECORD_ORDER` number). Below a sample of the desired output table:

```
RECORD_ID,KEYWORD1,KEYWORD2,KEYWORD3,FIRST_INI_SUBM_DATE,LAST_INI_SUBM_DATE,...  
1657,CUST,LOW,L1,03-Oct-17,08-Oct-17,...  
2378,COMP,MEDIUM,L2,03-Oct-17,03-Oct-17,...  
3133,VEND,HIGH,L3,03-Jun-17,08-Jun-17,...
```

I'm struggling to find the right approach to realise this through MAX.
I need a kind of statement like : give me the three dates for phase equals "initiate", lowest record order match and again for highest record order match.

I successfully created a statement which gives me the lowest and highest record_order number for each of the phases:

```
SELECT  
TABLE1.RECORD_ID,  
TABLE1.KEYWORD1,  
TABLE1.KEYWORD2,  
TABLE1.KEYWORD3,  
MIN(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'INITIATE' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS INIMIN,  
MIN(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'INVESTIGATE' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS INVMIN,  
MIN(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'APPROVED' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS APPMIN,  
MIN(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'IMPLEMENT' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS IMPMIN,  
MAX(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'INITIATE' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS INIMAX,  
MAX(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'INVESTIGATE' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS INVMAX,  
MAX(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'APPROVED' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS APPMAX,  
MAX(CASE WHEN PT.PHASE = 'IMPLEMENT' THEN PT.ETQ$RECORD_ORDER END) AS IMPMAX  

FROM  
TABLE1  
LEFT JOIN  
TABLE2 PT ON PT.RECORD_ID = TABLE1.RECORD_ID   

GROUP BY TABLE1.RECORD_ID, TABLE1.KEYWORD1, TABLE1.KEYWORD2, TABLE1.KEYWORD3
```

I'm struggling to pull the corresponding dates, please advice.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please consider this advice about not using images for code or data on these forum - see the link [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). You should present your tables as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo (…);`) and your data as DML (INSERT INTO foo VALUES (…);`). There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? Finally (and I don't wish to nag! :-) ), please **always** include your server version - it can be very helpful in giving an appropriate answer!

Comment: p.p.s. a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7e7901b0175235ae5c17cf7b2ed9a66) is always a good way of providing the DDL and DML - but also please copy to the question - think [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)!